# How to open external link from UIWebView not in my App, but in Safari? SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, safari, uiwebview

I would like to open all external links which are in my application
(`UIWebView`) not inside the app, but in Safari. How can I do that?
I have implement UiWebViewDelegate.

> Working solution for my question bellow:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked{
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)
    return false
}
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Leo Dabus thanks a lot for this hint, but I guess I have a better solution:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

this one works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for objective-c :-
in `ViewController.h`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

in `ViewController.m`

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked){
        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```